# How to cache response in iOS and show only when internet is not available?

Tags: ios, swift, caching, alamofire, urlsession

I want to cache the response of API. When the internet is available it should fetch data from the server and should update locally cached data every time and when the internet is not available it should show cached data. Is it possible with `Alamofire or URLSession`? or do I need to use a database and I should manually handle this?

Comment: I believe you can set `URLRequest.cachePolicy` to either `.returnCacheDataDontLoad` or `.returnCacheDataElseLoad` depending on your use case.

Comment: These are not working. it's only the first time fetching data from the server then every time returning from the cache whether the internet is available or not. What I want is always fetch new data from the server and every time update the local cache with the latest data and show that data when the internet is not available. @koropok

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What if you did something like this using `URLRequest`

```
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
// Configure your URLRequest as you wish with headers etc

// Load from the cache
urlRequest.cachePolicy = .returnCacheDataDontLoad

// Load from the source
if networkStatus == available {
    urlRequest.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
}

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { [weak self] data, response, error in

   // You will get data from the source when internet is available
   // You will get data from your cache when internet isn't available
   if let data = data {
      // Reload your UI with new or cached data
   }

   // There is some error in your request or server
   // Or the internet isn't available and the cache is empty
   if let error = error {
      // Update your UI to show an error accordingly
   }

}

task.resume()
```

**Update based on OPs comment**

> I'm opening the application first time and the internet is there and
> data is loaded from the server. now I'm closing my internet and
> opening the app but data will not be displayed because it didn't store
> data in the cache when the internet was there because of
> reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData this policy. this policy doesn't store
> data in cache.

Setting the `cachePolicy` to `reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` does not mean don't store any data in cache, it means ignore anything stored in cache and get data from the source.

Using the default `shared` singleton of URLSession makes use of a default cache as per the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1409000-shared#:%7E:text=The%20shared%20session%20uses%20the%20shared%20URLCache%2C%20HTTPCookieStorage%2C%20and%20URLCredentialStorage%20objects%2C%20uses%20a%20shared%20custom%20networking%20protocol%20list%20(configured%20with%20registerClass(_%3A)%20and%20unregisterClass(_%3A))%2C%20and%20is%20based%20on%20a%20default%20configuration.)

From the docs

> The shared session uses the shared URLCache, HTTPCookieStorage, and
> URLCredentialStorage objects, uses a shared custom networking protocol
> list (configured with registerClass(*:) and unregisterClass(*:)), and
> is based on a default configuration.

Give this a try, I tried based on the use case you mentioned above and it does what you want it to do.

Comment: In this case `reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` --> It'll not store response in cache!! So, there is no cache data, and when we don't have internet we'll not have anything to display.

Comment: @KetanParmar It depends on your sequence of events but I think this can work. When using `reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` with internet, it **will** store data in your cache. Try making a request with a valid internet connection and then once you get a response, switch your internet off and then retry your network request, you will not get an error but you will get a success response which is loaded from your cache.

Comment: @KetanParmar And when you do not have internet in the first place, of course there will be no data in the cache and you will get an `error` which has to be handled at your end but this was not your question.

Comment: I have added some updates to my answer to explain my thought process.

Comment: you're not getting me I think. for example, I'm opening the application first time and the internet is there and data is loaded from the server. now I'm closing my internet and opening the app but data will not be displayed because it didn't store data in the cache when the internet was there because of `reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` this policy. this policy doesn't store data in cache.

Comment: @KetanParmar - `reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` does not mean don't store anything in cache, it means ignore anything stored in cache. See my updates for further explanation and give it a try at your end. I just tried it for your use case and it loads the data from the cache once offline.

Comment: @Shwan I tried it and it's working with `URLRequest`. I was trying by configuring `URLSessionConfiguration.default.requestCachePolicy`. it's not working with this. I'm using `alamofire` and calling methods like this  `sessionManager.request(convertible, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: encoding, headers: headers)`. can you guide me how to handle with this mechanism? and thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: @KetanParmar - I don't work with AlamoFire too much so I am not sure. I believe it is just a wrapper for URLSession. You can have a look at `https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#adding-a-cachedresponsehandler` and `https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#response-caching` to see if it gives you some clues, if still not successful, I will try an example a bit later if time permits to see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Hey, i managed to handle this with `alamofire` as well. btw thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

With `Alamofire`, It can be achieved as below,

```
import Alamofire

class NetworkLogger: EventMonitor {
    
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.ketan.almofire.networklogger")
    
    func requestDidFinish(_ request: Request) {
        print(request.description)
    }
    
    func request<Value>(
        _ request: DataRequest,
        didParseResponse response: DataResponse<Value, AFError>
    ) {
        guard let data = response.data else {
            return
        }
        if let json = try? JSONSerialization
            .jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) {
            print(json)
        }
    }
}

class APIClient {
    
    private var manager = Session()
    
    init() {
        configureSession()
    }
    
    private func manageCachePolicy() {
        
        if NetworkReachabilityManager()?.isReachable ?? false {
            manager.sessionConfiguration.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
        } else {
            manager.sessionConfiguration.requestCachePolicy = .returnCacheDataElseLoad
        }
    }
    
    private func configureSession() {
        
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.requestCachePolicy = .returnCacheDataElseLoad
        if NetworkReachabilityManager()?.isReachable ?? false {
            configuration.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
        }
        
        manager = Session(configuration: configuration, eventMonitors: [NetworkLogger()])
        
        ///When we don't want network logs
        // manager = Session(configuration: configuration)
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Request
    func requestData(_ convertible: URLConvertible,
                     method: HTTPMethod = .get,
                     parameters: Parameters? = nil,
                     encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default,
                     headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil,
                     completion: @escaping (Result<Data, ErrorResult>) -> Void) {
        
        manageCachePolicy()
        manager.request(convertible,
                        method: method,
                        parameters: parameters,
                        encoding: encoding,
                        headers: headers).validate().responseData
        { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                completion(.success(data))
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(.network(string: error.localizedDescription)))
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```