# Alamofire: How to conditionally change cache policy based on network status?

Tags: swift, caching, alamofire

The end result I would like to achieve is to use cached data when the network is unavailable and load data from the server when the network is available.

The closest thing I've found is this thread, but I am still having trouble getting it to work using Alamofire.
[How to cache response in iOS and show only when internet is not available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71420354/how-to-cache-response-in-ios-and-show-only-when-internet-is-not-available/71421906)

I have two classes, one to check the network status and another that configures an Alamofire url session. Detecting the network status seems to be working, but it's not changing the session configuration. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

**NetworkReachability.shared.startNetworkMonitoring() is run when the app loads in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.**

```
class NetworkReachability {
    static let shared = NetworkReachability()
    let reachabilityManager = NetworkReachabilityManager(host: "www.google.com")

    func startNetworkMonitoring() {
        reachabilityManager?.startListening(onUpdatePerforming: { status in
            switch status {
            case .notReachable:
                ApiManager.configuration.requestCachePolicy = .returnCacheDataDontLoad
            case .reachable(.cellular):
                ApiManager.configuration.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringCacheData
            case .reachable(.ethernetOrWiFi):
                ApiManager.configuration.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringCacheData
            case .unknown:
              print("Unknown network state")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**A custom api manager to configure the cache.**

```
class ApiManager {
    static let shared = ApiManager()
    static let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.af.default
    
    public let sessionManager: Alamofire.Session = {
        let responseCacher = ResponseCacher(behavior: .modify { _, response in
          let userInfo = ["date": Date()]
          return CachedURLResponse(
            response: response.response,
            data: response.data,
            userInfo: userInfo,
            storagePolicy: .allowed)
        })

        return Session(
            configuration: configuration,
            cachedResponseHandler: responseCacher)
    }()
}
```

Comment: I wrote an answer for a similar question not too long ago for URLSession: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71421906/1619193 - have a look if this helps as I believe AlamoFire has similar caching mechanisms to URLSession

Comment: Thanks @ShawnFrank, I saw your answer and it makes sense. Unfortunately, I haven't had luck achieving the same outcome with Alamofire. I saw that the OP that you answered said that they had, but they didn't share how, and I don't have the reputation points to be able to comment there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing my `APIClient` here which I've written using `Alamofire`.

```
import Alamofire

class NetworkLogger: EventMonitor {
    
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.ketan.almofire.networklogger")
    
    func requestDidFinish(_ request: Request) {
        print(request.description)
    }
    
    func request<Value>(
        _ request: DataRequest,
        didParseResponse response: DataResponse<Value, AFError>
    ) {
        guard let data = response.data else {
            return
        }
        if let json = try? JSONSerialization
            .jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) {
            print(json)
        }
    }
}

class APIClient {
    
    private var manager = Session()
    
    init() {
        configureSession()
    }
    
    private func manageCachePolicy() {
        
        if NetworkReachabilityManager()?.isReachable ?? false {
            manager.sessionConfiguration.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
        } else {
            manager.sessionConfiguration.requestCachePolicy = .returnCacheDataElseLoad
        }
    }
    
    private func configureSession() {
        
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.requestCachePolicy = .returnCacheDataElseLoad
        if NetworkReachabilityManager()?.isReachable ?? false {
            configuration.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
        }
        
        manager = Session(configuration: configuration, eventMonitors: [NetworkLogger()])
        
        ///When we don't want network logs
        // manager = Session(configuration: configuration)
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Request
    func requestData(_ convertible: URLConvertible,
                     method: HTTPMethod = .get,
                     parameters: Parameters? = nil,
                     encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default,
                     headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil,
                     completion: @escaping (Result<Data, ErrorResult>) -> Void) {
        
        manageCachePolicy()
        manager.request(convertible,
                        method: method,
                        parameters: parameters,
                        encoding: encoding,
                        headers: headers).validate().responseData
        { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                completion(.success(data))
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(.network(string: error.localizedDescription)))
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ketan! This was insightful, but I believe the issue I keep running into is that I am unable to alter the session configuration once it has been instantiated. Upon further research the documentation states that "Once configured, the session object ignores any changes you make to the URLSessionConfiguration object." https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration. For my use case, I'd like the change the cache policy when the network changes, but I'm not sure that is possible now using Alamofire/URLSessionConfiguration.

Comment: You ApiManager is singleton I think. Maybe that's why you're not able to do this. see my code I'm configuring a session every time.

Comment: That makes sense. However, in my attempts to create a new session for every request, I instead get sessionDeinitialized errors and my requests are not able to complete. I would usually use a Singleton to maintain a reference to the session for the lifetime of the request, but then I can't modify the configuration :(