# Why does WKWebView load cache contents when it should not?

Tags: ios, swift, caching, wkwebview

I'm experiencing a weird `WKWebView` behaviour and I'm running out of ideas.

- Sometimes, let's say 1 in 50 loads, the `WKWebView` would not perform a fresh request but load a cached one instead.
- `URLRequest` uses default configuration. I am not setting custom [cache policy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest/cachepolicy). So the request should use the default  `NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.useProtocolCachePolicy`

```swift
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
wkWebView.load(request)
```

- The server responds with the following `Cache-Control` header

```
public, max-age=9, s-maxage=2592000
```

- What I found by logging the request details is that sometimes `WKWebView` would set the cache policy to `.returnCacheDataElseLoad`. This means that WKWebView would show outdated content, loading it from local cache.

> [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest/cachepolicy/returncachedataelseload) says:
> **`NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.returnCacheDataElseLoad`**
> Use existing cache data, regardless or age or expiration date, loading from originating source only if there is no cached data.

What seems to be a fix is clearing the cache using:

```swift
WKWebsiteDataStore.default().removeData(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes(),
                                        for: records,
                                        completionHandler: {
})
```

However, this is an overkill as it also clears other things that should be cached longer (e.g. images).

- Why does `WKWebView` decide to use `.returnCacheDataElseLoad`?
- What could be the reason that the web view does not run the request but loads it from the cache, effectively ignoring backend cache policy?

Comment: Sometimes if the network connection is't available then it will shift it's policy to checking the cache but this is very rare though.

This answer here gives a solution to this issue. 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71421906/4389257